# Neutral wires are burning hot, saw an ember

Tags: electrical, receptacle, neutral

Removed the outlet and the three connected neutral wires were insanely hot. Have an extension cord running a heater, could it be the draw or do I just need a new outlet?

Comment: Was the outlet itself hot?  Was the neutral screw terminal on the outlet hot?  **What else is on this circuit?** Is the wire big enough for the breaker? What possessed you to open up the receptacle, was the cord plug hot or burnt?   *Heater on an extension cord is bad, but it's NOT the cause of this here, so it should be disregarded for troubleshooting this*.

Comment: Back stab outlet? Or were the wires attached to screws?   Could also be a screwed up MWBC (multi wire branch circuit). I'm to the point where I hate MWBCs.

Comment: I agree with George, heaters create warm wires with good conditions but backstabs or an incorrectly wired mwbc , even a loose wire nut can all cause  the issues observed.

Comment: Get a pro. The issue might be in your panel, your wiring, your appliance... While we here are nice and helpful, there's nothing like a set of experienced eyes looking at the big picture.

Answer (score 1):

No, normal heating will not scorch the insulation and certainly won't make an glowing connection. I'd definitely disconnect that space heater before a fire starts and you probably ought to turn off that breaker to be safe.  Get it checked out, it could be nothing more than a loose connection, it could be something more complicated.

Comment: Would i start by changing all of the outlets and redoing the connections? Or check every switch and outlet on that circuit first for bad connections?

Comment: Well usually a glowing connection is (almost literally) a red flag but if it's more complicated than that, you could (again literally) be playing with fire so maybe this is one to call in a professional.